# How to convert a JSON file from GET request into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm trying to convert json obtained from a python GET request (requests library) into a pandas dataframe.

I've tried some other solutions on the subject, including json_normalize, however it does not appear to be working. The dataframe appears as a single column with dictionary's.

```
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=head)
data = response.json()
#what now?
```

gives me the following json:

```
"data": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10T11:40:13.437Z",
            "score": 87,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": 20.010000228881836
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": 34.4900016784668
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 418
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 166
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "comp": "lux",
                    "value": 961.4000244140625
                },
                {
                    "comp": "spl_a",
                    "value": 45.70000076293945
                }
            ],
            "indices": [
                {
                    "comp": "temp",
                    "value": -1
                },
                {
                    "comp": "humid",
                    "value": -2
                },
                {
                    "comp": "co2",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "voc",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "comp": "pm25",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        }
```

How do i convert this into a dataframe? The end result is supposed to look have the following headers:

[image]

Comment: what shoulds headers to be?

Comment: It is shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

you can `import json` in order use json package.

json package has `loads()` method, you can use this method convert json object to dict object, then by giving key to this dict object to get value to put it into dataframe.